# Button with variable width but constrained within parent - iOS Autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, autolayout

I want a variable width button, i.e. when there is small amount of text it is just wide enough to show the text (see image 1), and when there is a lot of text it extends its width up to a point and then starts to wrap (see image 2).

The problem I have is that when the text is long the button just extends off the screen (see image 3), I realise this is due to there not being a leading space constraint with the superview. However, if I add a leading space constraint the button would not be variable width and would always be full width of the space (see image 2).

What constraints do I need to add in addition to the trailing and top space constraints in image 1 in order to achieve what I need? Can it be done?

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

**Image 3:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the leading constraint to be `>=` instead of `=`.